# Windows phone longListSelector group by month and year

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I have the following class for grouping

```
public class StringKeyGroup<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public delegate string GetKeyDelegate(T item);
    public string Key { get; private set; }
    public StringKeyGroup(string key)
    {
        Key = key;
    }
    public static ObservableCollection<StringKeyGroup<T>> CreateGroups(IEnumerable<T> items, CultureInfo ci, GetKeyDelegate getKey, bool sort)
    {
        var list = new ObservableCollection<StringKeyGroup<T>>();

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var itemKey = getKey(item).ToLower();

            var itemGroup = list.FirstOrDefault(li => li.Key == itemKey);
            var itemGroupIndex = itemGroup != null ? list.IndexOf(itemGroup) : -1;

            if (itemGroupIndex == -1)
            {
                list.Add(new StringKeyGroup<T>(itemKey));
                itemGroupIndex = list.Count - 1;
            }
            if (itemGroupIndex >= 0 && itemGroupIndex < list.Count)
            {
                list[itemGroupIndex].Add(item);
            }
        }
        if (sort)
        {
            string[] months = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" };



            foreach (var group in list)
            {
                //group.ToList().Sort((c0, c1) => ci.CompareInfo.Compare(getKey(c0), getKey(c1)));               

            }



        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

and this my data source.

```
public class Data {
    public string Name {get;set;}

    public string Month {get;set;}
 }
```

the thing is the months is appear like : 
december 2013, june 2013 , january 2013

i want the data like
january 2013, june 2013, december 2013 and so on.
it depends on the month then the year
Oldest to latest.
I've been searching and i didn't find anything,
please help.

Comment: sort your data wise date than group

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't get it

Comment: sort your data by date so January will go first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this.
Instead of sorting the strings.
i used integers

public int month.

and i already have a list of Data called collection for example.

i used the following

var OrderedData = collection.OrderBy( x => x.Month).ToList();

if you want to sort more than one property u can do the following

var OrderedData = collection.OrderBy( x => x.Month).ThenBy(y => y.YourPropertyName).ToList();